# Не получается получить ImageData

Tags: javascript, изображения, html-canvas

Мне надо найти способ импортировать изображение в виде ImageData.
Я пробовал это делать через canvas но появлялась ошибка(она была не только у меня но всеравно решения не нашел).
Вот код с поблемой.
Возможно можно будет исправить

```
    function getImageData(el) {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const img = document.getElementById(el);
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      return context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
let imgD=getImageData("img")
```

Ошибка:Uncaught DOMException DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: судя по всему, ты пытаешься рисовать картинку, которая не успела загрузиться

Comment: я пытался и таким
var img = new Image(300,300)


img.onload = function() {

     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    

     imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,img.width,img.height);
 };
 

img.src = "image.png";

Comment: и все равно получал ту же ошибку?

Comment: сама картинка открывается? Возможно что-то не так с самой картинкой

Comment: Другая.С картинкой все норм.
Сама ошибка Uncaught DOMException DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Comment: какой `url` ты устанавливал? Какой урл был в браузере когда ты пробовал?

Comment: «The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data» — ну собственно вот и причина. Надо настраивать сервер и добавить атрибут crossorigin https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: @AlexeyTen а если это локально а не на сервере.
мне нужно чтобы можно было узнать цвет отдельного пикселя в изображении

Comment: @Grundy если я правильно понял то это url по типу file:///C:/какойто путь

Comment: Никак. Поднимайте сервер

Comment: @КарасёвАртемий, да, при запуске просто как локальный файл (протокол `file:///`) будут проблемы. Нужно поднимать локальный сервер и на нем пробовать. В этом случае будет работать вариант с `onload`